# C# and SQL Server database code explanation

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I do not understand what this code dela could you say what does it do? Here are the parts of the code do not understand and I would like to understand.

Here entire project download

http://leteckaposta.cz/857080848

**ONE**

```
object[] login = new object[Tables.AtributtesCount];

int j = 0;

foreach (object o in li)
{
                login[j] = o;

                if (j == Tables.AtributtesCount - 1)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(login);
                    j = 0;
                }
                else
                    j++;
}
```

**Two**

```
for (int i = 0; i < Tables.AtributtesCount; i++)
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Tables.Get_Atribut(i).Get_NameD, Tables.Get_Atribut(i).Get_Name);
```

Comment: are you using the code, or do you want to know what is the purpuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code **ONE** is populating a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  The line

```
if (j == Tables.AtributtesCount - 1)
```

detects the end of a row, beginning of the next row.  It is unclear where `li` is coming from, but whatever is in there is being placed into the data grid view.

Code **TWO** is defining the columns of that DataGridView (providing the metadata for the columns).  The two parameters to [Add(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f7a54z8(v=vs.110).aspx) are the column name and the column header.